# How to secure an API when the consumer uses claims authentication

Tags: security, authentication, oauth, adfs, api-design

## Background

I'm building a .NET MVC enterprise web application that must have the ability to authenticate users from different companies. One of the major requirements was to ensure that users don't need to create and remember new credentials to use the application, instead they should continue to use whatever credentials they use to access applications within their company intranet.

Since the application will be hosted on the extranet and needs to handle authenticating against multiple domains (i.e. multiple Active Directories), we are expecting each client to set up a security token service (AD FS) that the application can interface with to implement claims authentication.

The MVC application will check if the user is authenticated, and if not, start the workflow that ends with the MVC application being given a SAML claim being associated with the user.

## Problem

At this point, the user is authenticated and given access to the MVC application. However, the application itself is a modern day web application that uses quite a bit of JavaScript to consume a .NET Web API that handles most of the business logic. **My main question is how I can secure this API**. I want to make sure the only requests being sent to this server are being sent from a valid source, and that the user consuming the service has permissions to do so.

## Current Solutions

There are two approaches I can take to consume the API:

1. Straight from JavaScript (Preferred solution)
2. Route the request through the MVC server, which will then forward it to the API.

In order to pick an approach, I first need to find a way to secure the API.

### HMAC Authentication

The most straight forward solution I've found is HMAC Authentication - http://bitoftech.net/2014/12/15/secure-asp-net-web-api-using-api-key-authentication-hmac-authentication/. However, this approach requires all API requests to come directly from the MVC server, since the secret key will need to sit on the MVC server.

### OAuth 2.0

The second approach I can implement is some flavor of OAuth 2.0. The flavors I'm familiar with can be found here http://alexbilbie.com/guide-to-oauth-2-grants/:

- Authorization Code
- Implicit
- Resource owner credentials
- Client credentials

#### Authorization Code Grant

This is not the approach that I want to take. The MVC application has already received claims for the user - they shouldn't have to do it again just because the API needs the claim. (I have a followup question asking if I can simply pass the claim to the API server)

#### Implicit Grant

I like the way this approach sounds, since I will be able to execute API requests in the client (i.e. JavaScript code), however it suffers from the same problem as the first approach.

#### Resource Owner Credentials Grant

This approach is out of the question - I don't want either the MVC application or the API to ever hold onto the user's credentials.

#### Client Credentials Grant

This approach is the only reasonable OAuth approach listed - however I fail to see a major difference between this approach and HMAC authentication detailed above.

## Questions

1. Have I correctly set up the MVC application's authentication structure? Specifically, in this context is it appropriate to have AD FS handle authentication and respond with SAML tokens representing user claims?
2. I plan to store user data in the server's session. Can I also store the user's claim in the session, and then somehow send that up to the API for authentication?
3. If I *can* pass the claim from the MVC server to the API server, and the API server can correctly authenticate the request, is it safe to pass the claim to the client (browser / JS code) so that consuming the API can bypass the MVC server?
4. Is the HMAC Authentication approach the best way to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, using ADFS or any IdP products as an IdP for your application is a good way to implement SSO. Doing this way help you delegate all the federated access management as well as claim rules to ADFS.
2. Yes, you can store claims in session and somehow send them to the WebAPI. Please note that if you are using WIF, it already stores claims in Thread.CurrentPrincipal as a ClaimsPrincipal object. Another thing is that I assume you only want to somehow send the claims only, not the whole SAML2 token.
3. I would say it is as safe as the mechanism you use to protect the token on the client side. Check https://auth0.com/blog/ten-things-you-should-know-about-tokens-and-cookies/ and https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/80727/best-place-to-store-authentication-tokens-client-side for more details.
4. I can't say if it is best for you, but it seems to be a viable way, given that you have control over the WebAPI too. However, it also seems that using JWT token would be easier: https://vosseburchttechblog.azurewebsites.net/index.php/2015/09/19/generating-and-consuming-json-web-tokens-with-net/. Talking about JWT token, you can also ask ADFS to issue it for you: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/maheshu/2015/05/26/json-web-token-jwt-support-in-adfs/.